# How to make a library in c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, package

I am writing a small application in c++ and I have some questions regarding that.  I am basically a Java developer now moving into c++.

1. If I use some library like boost, curl etc. can I make it run without installing that on the client machine (I mean something like including all library jar files inside the project in Java)
2. I have installed some library or software in linux. After that if I type in the terminal it pings the software.  For example php, after you install it you can use php from terminal.  How does this work? Can I use my simple c++ project to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. You use a process called *static linking*, which links all the libraries into one big executable.  In `./configure` scripts (from autotools), you use the `--enable-static` flag. When building your program, you use the `-static` flag.  The static libraries are the ones with the `.a` suffixes; shared libraries use `.so`, sometimes with a version number suffix).
2. PHP is not a library, it is a language (i.e. executable) which provides its own command-line interface. Your C++ executable can work similarly, you just have to get the input from `cin` (in `<iostream>`) and write results to `cout`, using `cerr` for error messages.

Your title question, "How to make a library in c++ in linux" (as opposed to using a library): You use the `ar` program to link several `.o` files into a single `.a` library file. You can also use `ranlib` to clean up the `.a` file. Read the `man` pages for those commands to see how they are used.

Answer (score 2):

1)Answer to your Q1 is compilation with libraries statically linked. For example with gcc Compiler:

**# gcc -static myfile.c -o myfile**

2)Answer to you Q2 is appending the absolute path of executable to $PATH Environment Variable. For example in Bash shell:

**# export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user/pathofexecutable**

The above setup will be temporary only for that terminal you do. To make it available to all terminal in you machine add the above export command to */home/user/.bashrc* file.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, you want to compile the program as a static executable. (Just pass `-static` to g++.) It will make the program much larger since it needs to include a copy of stuff normally kept as libraries.

For question 2 I'm pretty sure what you mean is having a program in the `PATH`. Type `echo $PATH` to see the path on your current machine. If you install your program in one of those directories it will run from anywhere. (Most likely `/usr/local/bin/`)